# .net DateTime MaxValue is different once it is stored in database

Tags: c#, .net, sql, datetime

When I store date property with value DateTime.MaxValue in database and retrieve it back, the stored value does not equal to DateTime.MaxValue.  The tick properties are off.   Why is this?

Using MS SQL, data type for date field is 'datetime'

[image]

Comment: What database are you using and what data type in the database is storing the date?

Comment: Did you try datetime2? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx

Comment: +1 for good question. I've also noticed that if you use DateTime.MaxValue in a Linq2Sql query, the date value will be translated into SQL minus the 3 millseconds as explained in the answer... this means that you don't even have to store the value in a database to get this discrepancy. Furthermore, if you use DateTime.MinValue in a Linq2Sql query, you will get a SqlException stating that the date `Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM` for the same reason.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Because SQL datetime has lower resolution.

> The DateTime data type in MS SQL
>   represents Date and time data from
>   January 1, 1753, to December 31, 9999,
>   with an accuracy of one
>   three-hundredth second, or 3.33
>   milliseconds. Values are rounded to
>   increments of .000, .003, or .007
>   milliseconds.

[source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258277%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

> The DateTime value type in .Net
>   represents dates and times from
>   12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001
>   Anno Domini (Common Era) through
>   11:59:59 P.M., December 31, 9999 A.D.
>   (C.E.) Time values are measured in
>   100-nanosecond units called ticks.

[source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: FWIW - I was told that this will be fixed in SQL Server 2010 (or whatever they'll release it as) so that the DateTime data types match.

Comment: @dolphy, to a certain extent they already have "fixed" it in SQL 2008--it has new date and time datatypes that will allow for more (or less) precision. I doubt very much that MS will ever change how the "old" datetime data types works, as that would break a heck of a lot of existing code and piss off much of their existing customer base.

Comment: @Philip Kelley -- that's exactly what I was referring to.  I didn't realize that had done this in SQL 2008.  I guess that shows that my company is still on SQL 2005 :-)

Answer (score 3):

It could very well be cause a .NET DateTime doesn't directly translate to the SQL DateTime type.

I would both set the value and then check the ticks against [`SqlDateTime.MaxValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqldatetime.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I must admit I'm not certain on this, but it could be to do with the accuracy of datetime?

Doing a quick search here is an article on the
[Precision and accuracy of DateTime](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/04/08/precision-and-accuracy-of-datetime.aspx)

Also perhaps there is a mistmatch between the precision of datetime in c# vs sql?

Answer (score 0):

Of what type is the data field in which you're storing this value?

It could be that the maximum value for a .NET `DateTime` exceeds the capacity for the equivalent data type in the database engine.

Answer (score 0):

MS SQL Server does some odd things with dates at the lowest level. For example consider the following script:

```
select
    test1 = dateadd(ms,-1,convert(datetime,'20110504')),
    test2 = dateadd(ms,-2,convert(datetime,'20110504')),
    test3 = dateadd(ms,-3,convert(datetime,'20110504')),
    test4 = dateadd(ms,-4,convert(datetime,'20110504')),
    test5 = dateadd(ms,-5,convert(datetime,'20110504')),
    test6 = dateadd(ms,-6,convert(datetime,'20110504'))
```

This returns:

```
test1                   test2                   test3                   test4                   test5                   test6
----------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- -----------------------
2011-05-04 00:00:00.000 2011-05-03 23:59:59.997 2011-05-03 23:59:59.997 2011-05-03 23:59:59.997 2011-05-03 23:59:59.993 2011-05-03 23:59:59.993
```

As you can see MS SQL is only dealing with milliseconds to the nearest 3. If you go between these they get rounded off. Is possible that this is what's happening when DateTime.MaxValue is getting stored in SQL.